# The bounty contradiction (off topic)

Tags: discussion, bounty

Just a thought, but I've noticed that each time I've given a bounty, before the bonus expires, I end up with more points than before.

Do you have this same experience?

Is there a way of proving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your history, I'd say it's a coincidence (no offense). I've earned 80 rep this week for doing practically nothing new, and you've mostly just offered scant 50-point bounties. Most people who contribute to this site at least once or twice a week will earn more than that.

Now, on very-high-traffic sites like Stack Overflow, it's somewhat of a different story. There, questions tend to get buried very quickly, but bounties grant extra attention to the question, which often comes with upvotes for the people who asked or answered them. It's normal for anybody who participates in a bounty hunt to earn more rep than usual, even if they don't actually win the bounty.

But, on Seasoned Advice, bounties are really just gravy, a little extra incentive for people to answer. They don't really do that much in terms of getting attention, because questions stay on the front page for a couple of days anyway. However, that is slowly changing as our views (and subsequent Q&A activities) continue to ramp up; already it's rare to see a question more than 2 days old on the front page, so we may very well get to the point where bounties become a sort of personal investment like they are on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, and no offence taken.